# Ada- attempting to remove blank spaces from a string?

Tags: string, ada

This question is in regards to a program I'm working on for an intro to programming class in Ada. The only packages I can use are the basic text, integer, and float packages. I'm writing a procedure right now to remove the spaces from the string and I keep getting a constraint error on the same line. This is the line:

```
if inputString(count) /= Character'Val(32) then
```

I have count set to start at 1 and then increment through a loop until the end of the string, which would in turn check each character of the string to see if it was different than the character value of a blank space (32). I was then going to include this line:

```
noSpace(count..count) := inputString(count..count)
```

where noSpace is to be the string with no spaces. My line of thinking may be completely off and I may need to approach this from a completely different angle.

**Update**: I've now managed to get past the error message and successfully remove the spaces from my string. But now when I print the new string there is a random variety of characters and shaded spaces after it. I believe the problem is caused because the new string is shorter than the previous one and the last characters are different.

Comment: Why are you using `Character'Val(32)` rather than just `' '`?

Comment: I was actually trying to use both to see if I got an error with only one or the other. I got the same error with both unfortunately haha.

Comment: `' '` and `'Character'Val(32)'` are identical. `' '` is much clearer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to remember that in the future!

Comment: What are you doing with the places that did contain spaces? Does the string shrink? and does package Ada.Strings.Fixed count as a basic package?

Comment: @NWS For the lines that aren't spaces I have: Else null;  I am trying to shrink the string. And I can't use that package. I finally got past the error I was getting and now when it prints the new string to me it successfully removes the spaces but there's a variety of strange characters and shaded spaces after this. I believe this has to do with setting a new last character for the string?

Comment: You ought to post more of your code; a minimal example, cut down to show just the problem but capable of being compiled, is ideal. And even as a newcomer you have enough privilege to be able to edit your own question - posting code in comments doesn’t work.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the bug is hid somewhere else.

Try this:

```pascal
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure String_Remove_Space is

    function Count_Space( S : String ) return Natural is
        Sum_Of_Space : Natural := 0;
    begin
        for I in S'range loop
            if S(I) = ' ' then
                Sum_Of_Space := Sum_Of_Space + 1;
            end if;
        end loop;
        return Sum_Of_Space;
    end Count_Space;

    Input_String : String := "Apple is on the tree";
    Input_No : String := "AppleIsOnTheTree";

    No_Space : String(1..Input_String'Length - Count_Space(Input_String));

    Index : Positive := 1;
begin

    for I in Input_String'range loop
        if Input_String(I) /= ' ' then
            No_Space(Index) := Input_String(I);
            Index := Index + 1;
        end if;
    end loop;

    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Input_String);
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(No_Space);

end String_Remove_Space;
```

Comment: Definitely a good answer, although I tend to like Simon's approach better because it only makes one pass through the string.  Yup, still worried about squeezing out every last nanosecond...

Comment: @ajb, only one pass through the string *but* a lot more moves! In [my version](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29356929/40851), each non-space character will be moved as many times as there are spaces before it in the input string.

Comment: @SimonWright Oops, didn't look at your answer carefully.  I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If there are spaces in your input string, the valid part of the output string must be shorter. I imagine you wrote something like

```
noSpace : String := inputString;
```

to start things off with `noSpace` as long as it would need to be if there were no spaces in `inputString`? then, as you squeeze the spaces out, you seem to be writing garbage (undefined characters) to the end of `noSpace`. This doesn’t matter so long as you only deal with the valid part.

I tried this:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Lareaper is
   function Strip_Space (S : String) return String is
      Result : String := S;
      Current : Positive := Result'First;
      Last : Natural := Result'Last;
   begin
      loop
         exit when Current > Last; --  processed the whole string
         if Result (Current) = ' ' then
            --  slide the rest of the string back one
            Result (Current .. Last - 1) := Result (Current + 1 .. Last);
            --  which reduces the length by 1 too
            Last := Last - 1;
         else
            --  non-space character, skip
            Current := Current + 1;
         end if;
      end loop;
      --  return only the part of the result that doesn't contain spaces
      return Result (Result'First .. Last);
   end Strip_Space;
begin
   Put_Line ('|' & Strip_Space ("") & '|');
   Put_Line ('|' & Strip_Space (" ") & '|');
   Put_Line ('|' & Strip_Space ("a") & '|');
   Put_Line ('|' & Strip_Space ("ab") & '|');
   Put_Line ('|' & Strip_Space (" a") & '|');
   Put_Line ('|' & Strip_Space ("a ") & '|');
   Put_Line ('|' & Strip_Space ("a b") & '|');
   Put_Line ('|' & Strip_Space (" a b ") & '|');
end Lareaper;
```

which outputs

```
$ ./lareaper 
||
||
|a|
|ab|
|a|
|a|
|ab|
|ab|
```

Answer (score 1):

Count should start at InputString'First, not at 1.
In particular, when InputString is created as a slice/substring of another string, it is very likely that its first character is not at index 1.

Comment: I tried changing count to start at InputString'First and still received the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show you another possible solution, although one I would never use in real life:

```
function Strip_Space (S : String) return String is
begin
    if S'Length = 0 then
        return "";
    elsif S (S'First) = ' ' then
        return Strip_Space (S (S'First + 1 .. S'Last));
    else
        return S (S'First) & Strip_Space (S (S'First + 1 .. S'Last));
    end if;
end Strip_Space;
```

And then there's the way I would *really* do it.  I didn't read Simon's answer carefully enough to realize that he was sliding substrings around.  The most efficient answer, I think, is similar to Mark's, but you don't actually need to count the spaces in the string first.

```
function Strip_Space (Input_String : String) return String is
    No_Space : String(1..Input_String'Length);

    Index : Positive := 1;
begin

    for I in Input_String'range loop
        if Input_String(I) /= ' ' then
            No_Space(Index) := Input_String(I);
            Index := Index + 1;
        end if;
    end loop;

    return No_Space(1 .. Index - 1);
end Strip_Space;
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with recursion per se! (*not* in a restricted environment, of course)